# Setting up permissions for WordPress on Amazon EC2 (Amazon Linux)

Tags: linux, wordpress, permissions, amazon-ec2

I setup WordPress on an Amazon EC2 instance. It's using Amazon Linux and is a standard setup (just php5 and mysql).

WordPress works fine, but there's some permission issues. Specifically I can't upload media, update permalink, plugins, etc. I have no write permission under the ec2-user and because I uploaded all the files over WinSCP the current owner is ec2-user.

My question is what's the best way to correct this issue? I could probably fix it by changing ownership of all folders/files to root, but that's not a very elegant or dynamic solution.

The path to my web directory is /var/www/html. Can I allow the ec2-user the correct permissions? Perhaps by having a group that both the Apache user and ec2-user share?

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686125/update-wordpress-theme-on-ec2 and look at Jake's answer
Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I can work with the solution @stink suggested but If there is a elegant way where I don't have to switch ownership/permissions to make updates via FTP/web?

Answer (score 10):

See http://blog.david-jensen.com/development/wordpress-amazon-ec2-apache-permissions-wordpress/ among other Google results. He looks to have had good luck:

> I have been doing my best to figure out the Amazon EC2 Apache setup of
>   permissions to enable WordPress to be able to manage all of the files
>   on my Amazon EC2 instance without WordPress asking for FTP permissions
>   when I try to upload a plugin or theme via the Admin site. I ended up
>   having to give file and group ownership of the files in my html folder
>   to apache user for WordPress to run correctly.
>   http://www.chrisabernethy.com/why-wordpress-asks-connection-info/ and
>   its comments helped me reach this conclusion.

**From the webpage:**

Run

```
sudo su chown -R apache:apache /vol/html
```

I then set permissions to what the hardening WordPress guide recommends for my html root as all my WordPress files are there as I am running MultiSite with multiple domains.

```
find /vol/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /vol/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

As apache doesn’t have a login I feel this is worth the risk though there is probably a better way to do this. I then added ec2-user to the apache group and changed the permissions of the wp-content folder to have group write permission 775.

```
useradd -G apache ec2-user
sudo chmod -R 775 /vol/html/wp-content
```

This allows FileZilla or any other program logged in as ec2-user the ability to change files and folders in the wp-content folder only. If anyone has a better way of doing this I would like to know. I am only using SSH and SFTP to access the server with key files.

Answer (score 8):

I set the owner to ec2-user:apache, then perform the hardening, then adjust the group read+write permissions for the folders.

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /vol/html
sudo chmod -R 755 /vol/html

sudo find /vol/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /vol/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

sudo chgrp -R apache /vol/html
sudo chmod -R g+rw /vol/html
sudo chmod -R g+s /vol/html
```

Then edit  /wordpress-install/wp-config.php and define the fs_method

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Now wordpress can update/upload, etc.  And you can still SFTP files without changing the permissions every time.

Comment: sudo chmod -R g+rw /vol/html
sudo chmod -R g+s /vol/html did the trick for me. Thanks!!

Comment: sudo chmod -R g+rw is the same as: sudo chmod -R 775

Answer (score 3):

I tried the solution provided in the [answer by @markratledge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9548184/1268350) for my AWS EC2 instance (Amazon Linux).

Wordpress(apache) was good, but SFTP(ec2-user) was giving permission errors.

Then I tried the following:

I added ec2-user to the apache group:

```
usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
```

Next I set 'apache' as owner group and 'ec2-user' as owner user for the WordPress installation directory (/var/www/html in my case):

```
chown -R apache:ec2-user /var/www/html
```

Finally, WordPress was happy and I could SFTP too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

> To fix file permissions for the Apache web server
>
> Some of the available features in WordPress require write access to
>   the Apache document root (such as uploading media though the
>   Administration screens). The web server runs as the apache user, so
>   you need to add that user to the www group that was created in the
>   LAMP web server tutorial.
>
> Add the apache user to the www group.
>
> [ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo usermod -a -G www apache Change the file
>   ownership of /var/www and its contents to the apache user.
>
> [ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo chown -R apache /var/www Change the group
>   ownership of /var/www and its contents to the www group.
>
> [ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo chgrp -R www /var/www Change the directory
>   permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories to add group write
>   permissions and to set the group ID on future subdirectories.
>
> [ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo chmod 2775 /var/www [ec2-user wordpress]$
>   find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \; Recursively change
>   the file permissions of /var/www and its subdirectories to add group
>   write permissions.
>
> [ec2-user wordpress]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {}
>   \; Restart the Apache web server to pick up the new group and
>   permissions.
>
> [ec2-user wordpress]$ sudo service httpd restart Stopping httpd:
>   [  OK  ] Starting httpd:                                            [ 
>   OK  ]

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question searching for the answer. I set all ownership and group ownership to Apache. However, if I want to upload something ftp I have to ssh change permissions to ec2-user upload the file and change it back. I figured it was a small price to pay to have the permissions set to WordPress's recommended settings.