# Wordpress ask for fTP credentials for installing plugins

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have a WP site setup on AWS, and when I try to install a plugin it ask for FTP credentials. I tried to set `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` in my wp-config file trought ftp file but I dont have the permission to change those file. How do I change permissions to do this?

Comment: Will you find the answer on this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545607/setting-up-permissions-for-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2-amazon-linux

Comment: Thank you. I tried all on that side already. When trying to set permissions in terminal i get a "not pemritted2 error, when trying with sudo nothing happens so kinda stuck.