# Joomla Site is hacked?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

My joomla site is hacked by someone.The hacker change the content of my files and replace their content. I find it and deleted but again and again he is doing this.I changed my ftp and cpanel details.But no use.How to prevent this.Please help me any one

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What type of changes they made ? add content to your articles ? or made some file changes? anyway upgrade the site. set cpanel password for admin directory.

Comment: check your browser, is it any malware? and change the admin password.

Comment: @JobinJose they made some file changes.Actually I have my own content,functionality and features for joomla 1.5 so upgrading take much time.

Comment: @DRK Anyway try to upgrade bcoz your version is very old at least keep on 2.5. the other options are if the site targets only few countries block all other countries and try to use 2 factor authentication but Im not sure it available for 1.5. Also change mysql user passowrd too.

Comment: Have you ensured you're using the latest build for Joomla 1.5? (1.5.26). You can prevent this sort of thing by upgrading. Despite it being a big job, you should still upgrade to the latest version of Joomla as 1.5 is no longer supported and you're more prone to hacks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best methods to clean up a hacked site with no clean version available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337976/best-methods-to-clean-up-a-hacked-site-with-no-clean-version-available)

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, at least update to 1.5.26 and after that also install this **[patch](http://anything-digital.com/blog/security-updates/joomla-updates/joomla-15-security-patch-made-easy-to-install.html)**.

Remove any unneeded extensions and also try to make sure that the rest of your extensions are up-to-date as much as possible.

You can also strengthen up your site's security with advanced .htaccess rules and security extensions like admin tools by Akeeba.

**Read also:**

1. [Joomla Security Checklist](http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced)
2. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/what-to-do-if-my-joomla-website-got-hacked
3. Also, this [**Google Search Results Page**](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=my%20joomla%20site%20has%20been%20hacked&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl) will present you with links to useful and important information.