# My website is defaced — how do I fix it?

Tags: web

My website is defaced and every time I load it, there appears a page with some message in some Turkish language and the title of page is 'hacked by 58'.

I tried searching this web page in my `public_html` directory but couldn't find this html in any directory. Yet still it loads when we visit the website.

Any help?

Comment: Restore from a backup.

Comment: i dont have it. i dont have the backup

Comment: @Azam: That was a bad idea then.  If you don't have a copy of your website anymore, then you don't have a copy of your website anymore.  You can manually make changes to the production version, but without a "known working version" it's just a guessing game.

Comment: @Azam Contact your host and pray they have backups, then.

Comment: IMO, you should be keeping the source for your web site under a version control system so that you can reproduce it at any time.  One primary reason is so that if you are hacked, you can reinstate the original.  If you need more help, you'll need to identify which system you're using — which CMS (WordPress for example) and which o/s it is hosted on (Linux? Windows?) etc. Versions are also relevant — if you're not using the latest, upgrade. However, this is something that will be hard to work on for Stack Overflow — this sort of situation does not lend itself to a good SO-compatible question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best methods to clean up a hacked site with no clean version available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337976/best-methods-to-clean-up-a-hacked-site-with-no-clean-version-available)

Answer (score 0):

nginx or apache？ locate the configure file,inside the file there is a line kind of 'root',that's path of your index folder,enter that folder fix index.html.
Btw,if your server is hacked,it's highly possible running dangerous programs ,you'd better reinstall your sys,and try not to be hacked,such as use ssh-key login method.